# Hayflick's limit and cell division

Tags: cell-biology

Suppose the Hayflick's limit of a cell is 10 and it divides 10 times.  At this point, it undergoes differentiation.  Is it possible for it to undergo dedifferentiation at this point?

Answer (score -2):

I don't think so naturally. I think the general stream of the progeny goes stem cell => pluripotent cell => progenitor cell => specialised cell.